# What is the idiomatic way to compile a subset of the packages of a project?

Tags: java, gradle

We are replacing our home grown java build setup with gradle. It is a multi-project setup, and ne of the sub projects has a package structure like this:

```
com.whatever.ourproduct.api
com.whatever.ourproduct.base
com.whatever.ourproduct.foo
com.whatever.ourproduct.bar....
```

The "primary" requirement is simply to compile all packages together. But now we are told that `com.whatever.ourproduct.api` **also** needs to be compiled (with different javac options) to a different output location.

Now I am wondering whether there is a canonical/idiomatic way to achieve this. Should there be a separate project just for that one package?

Comment: Put that into a subproject and give its its own settings

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry, didnt mention that: this is a multi project build. So it is already a sub project.

Comment: Just make the `api` package another subproject then!

Comment: @BoristheSpider You mean: declaring another sibling sub project that points is source set ... into the src folder of the "big" subproject that has all the packages?

Comment: Personally I’d just move the sources into a new subproject. But your approach might work too. A little less idiomatic though so probably harder to find docs on...